# Problems with Codecademy Python course

Tags: python

Trying to teach myself Python via Codecademy. However, when I reach this section, it keeps returning the same error, no matter what I do. Anyone else encounter this problem, or know how to fix it? I'm a noob to coding of any way shape or form.
A screenshot of the error can be seen here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fG5IDRoZ3cXzZxbnlpT3RheHc/edit?usp=sharing

```
answer = 2
def the_flying_circus():
    if ______: answer + 5 = 7
    print "This gets Printed!"
    elif (answer < 5):
        print "As does this!"
    else end
```

The error is:

```
elif (answer < 5):
   ^
SynxtaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect for line 4.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in your indentation.

You can't have an `elif` unless it follows an `if` block. Because your if statement is on one line, and your next print statement is on the next line, you don't meet this requirement. I also don't know what you're intending to do with your `if ________:` section.

Here's a fix:

```
answer = 2
def the_flying_circus():
    if answer + 5 == 7:
        print "This gets Printed!"
    elif (answer < 5):
        print "As does this!"
    # ...
```

Comment: also note the == instead of the =.

Answer (score 0):

```
else: end you are missing a `:`
```

You have a lot of other syntax errors:

```
 if ______: answer + 5 = 7
```

You cannot assign to an operator.

Unless `end` is a variable defined somewhere  using `else: end` is not python syntax
Not sure what you want but from your code this seems more logical:

```
answer = 2
def the_flying_circus():
    if answer + 5 == 7:
        print "This gets Printed!"
    elif answer < 5:
        print "As does this!"
    else:
        return answer
```